# I want add a piece of code where the game checks if the players velocity along the Y axis is under a certain number

Tags: c#

The piece of code I want to write is where the game will check if the player is colliding with anything it will check this by looking at your y vector3 is under a certain number (its like this cause the gravity and collisions overall is a bit wonky) like if the players vector3 is under (0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f) then the game will call that line of code again if you're above that vector3 it will not call it again. My main problem trying solve this is telling unity who to check for which I'm not to sure how to do it. Whenever I do try to implement it all I get is errors sometimes I get really close but I'm unable to implement it due to some issues within the if statements.

As stated before I never was able to get implement I'll update things if I do figure it out on my own.

Comment: if you're really lost and don't know how to implement specific feature during game dev i suggest you post here instead of stack overflow https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/
SO is more about you made a code but it does not work.